# Required Qr code Detector sample using zxing

Tags: c#, zxing

I'm a beginer in QR code application and now I'm trying to develop application to detect QR code in the image. but i count not find any reference/sample in it.I'm using Zbar crossing zxing library and C# for this .kindly guide me in this or refer me some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

We've also experienced that it is hard to find working samples for zxing.Net. After combining some of them (I can't remember where we found them) and some trial and error we found this to be satisfactory (excerpt):

```
[DebuggerHidden]
string findQrCodeText(com.google.zxing.Reader decoder, Bitmap bitmap)
{
  var rgb = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
  var hybrid = new com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer(rgb);
  com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap binBitmap = new com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap(hybrid);
  string decodedString = decoder.decode(binBitmap, null).Text;
  return decodedString;
}
```

which is called by

```
findQrCodeText(new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader(), bitmap);
```

We do some image voodoo around that to obtain just a little better results, but I'm afraid can't disclose that. This piece of code is the zxing part, though.

We added the `DebuggerHiddenAttribute` because zxing throws and swallows tons of exceptions internally, which is a real PITA when running in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for your response.i tried your code its working great.but i'm trying image directly from the camera so its better if we detect qrcode befoure giving to the decode. so that i can mark and show the qrcode in the video. can you help me in this....

Thankyou

Cholan

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you mean, but this sounds like a different question. It is better to keep threads on-topic. Feel free to submit another question and fully clarify your intentions.

Comment: @GertArnold          * Looking over this i am interested to know if this piece of code will also be helpful in detecting the qrcode in a SCANNED Pdf file? 
         I have a document with a qrcode and when it is scanned - i want to detect where the qrcode is located(checking all four corners of file) so i can rotate the page so that 
          the qr code will always be on the left top corner (the qr code will always be on the top left corner).

Comment: @BB987 Sorry, I'm not on this any more. We only analyzed graphical file formats. Also, I think the library has changed significantly in the mean time.